# Subgraphs and homomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_{sub}$ be a subgraph of $G$.

When can one expect a homomorphism from $G$ to $G_{sub}$?

Are there any criteria - algebraic or spectral?

Any literature sources on this problem will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$G_{sub}$ is called a "retract".
Though retracts have been studied quite a bit, there seem to be only characterizations of retracts for specific classes of graphs (especially products of graphs).

An extensive study of homomorphism :
http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~ctardif/articles/ghss.pdf
Section 2.3 might be of interest.

In particular, $G$ and $G_{sub}$ must share the same chromatic number, odd girth and clique number.

Apparently, all these studies on retracts started with Hell's PhD thesis - however I can't seem to find it anywhere.
If somebody can find it I'd be glad.
The full reference is 
"P. Hell, Rétractions de graphes, Ph. D. Thesis, Université de Montréal, 1972."

Litterature on some classes of graphs :

Chordal graphs : 
http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~victor.chepoi/RetractsPCG.pdf

Trees, chordal graphs, others
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X85900627

Retracts of Hamming graphs : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9290054J